# How to preserve the not mapped properties of a collection in a destination object with Automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

**Initial Situation:**
I have a source and a destination object and both have a collection of `Elements`. With Automapper I map the source to the destination object. After that, I add information to properties which are only present on the destination object (`ItemName` and `ItemNumber`). Additionally, I add information to the property `Text` of the objects in the collection `AssetElementDto`. After that, I call `mapper.Map(source_update, destination);` to update the destination object.

**Question:**
When I run the code the information of `ItemName` and `ItemNumber` is preserved after the update. What can I do that also the information of the `AssetElementDto` of `Text` is preserved?

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().PreserveReferences();
            cfg.CreateMap<AssetElement, AssetElementDto>().PreserveReferences();
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        var source = new Source()
        {
            Name = "Sinonis",
            Id = new Random().Next(),
            Elements = new List<AssetElement>
            {
                new(){ Id = 1},
                new(){ Id = 2}
            }
        };

        var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
        destination.ItemNumber = 42;
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => e.Text ="Wow");

        destination.ItemName = "NPC21";

        var source_update = new Source()
        {
            Name = "Nindalf",
            Id = new Random().Next(),
            Elements = new List<AssetElement>
            {
                new(){ Id = 3},
                new(){ Id = 4}
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"Before update is: {destination.Name} {destination.Id} {destination.ItemNumber} {destination.ItemName}");
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($" {e.Id} {e.Text}"));

        mapper.Map(source_update, destination);

        Console.WriteLine($"After update is : {destination.Name} {destination.Id} {destination.ItemNumber} {destination.ItemName}");
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($" {e.Id} {e.Text}"));
    }
}

#region Source

public class Source
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;

    public List<AssetElement> Elements;

}

public class AssetElement
{
    public int Id;
}

#endregion

#region Destination

public class Destination
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;

    public List<AssetElementDto> Elements;

    public int ItemNumber;
    public string ItemName;
}

public class AssetElementDto
{
    public string Text;
    public int Id;
}

#endregion
```

**Console Output:**

`Wow` is not preserved after the update.

```
Before update is: Sinonis 1643275093 42 NPC21
 1 Wow
 2 Wow
After update is : Nindalf 75522068 42 NPC21
 3 null
 4 null
```

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) for this brief but powerful hint. This solved my problem. Please see the necessary changes in the code below. Here is the [link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) to AutoMapper.Collection.

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.EquivalencyExpression; //add using

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddCollectionMappers(); //add the collection mapper
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
            cfg.CreateMap<AssetElement, AssetElementDto>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.Id == o.Id); //add the equality compersion
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        var source = new Source()
        {
            Name = "Sinonis",
            Id = new Random().Next(),
            Elements = new List<AssetElement>
            {
                new(){ Id = 1},
                new(){ Id = 2}
            }
        };

        var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
        destination.ItemNumber = 42;
        destination.ItemName = "NPC21";
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => e.Text ="Wow");

       

        var source_update = new Source()
        {
            Name = "Nindalf",
            Id = new Random().Next(),
            Elements = new List<AssetElement>
            {
                new(){ Id = 1},//ID's need to be the same as before
                new(){ Id = 2}
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"Before update is: {destination.Name} {destination.Id} {destination.ItemNumber} {destination.ItemName}");
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($" {e.Id} {e.Text}"));

        mapper.Map(source_update, destination);

        Console.WriteLine($"After update is : {destination.Name} {destination.Id} {destination.ItemNumber} {destination.ItemName}");
        destination.Elements.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine($" {e.Id} {e.Text}"));
    }
}

#region Source

public class Source
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;

    public List<AssetElement> Elements;

}

public class AssetElement
{
    public int Id;
}


#endregion

#region Destination

public class Destination
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;

    public List<AssetElementDto> Elements;

    public int ItemNumber;
    public string ItemName;
}

public class AssetElementDto
{
    public string Text;
    public int Id;
}

#endregion
```

**Console:**

`Wow` is preserved in the collection after the update.

```
Before update is: Sinonis 49772274 42 NPC21
 1 Wow
 2 Wow
After update is : Nindalf 236466397 42 NPC21
 1 Wow
 2 Wow
```